# Mysql : SELECT multiple with different condition of selection for each

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this:

```
Date  DATA Country  
2013  3    UK
2013  1    UK
2012  2    UK
2013  5    DE
2012  4    DE
```

What I would like to do is:

```
Country  2012  2013
UK       1     2
DE       1     1
```

so in pseudo code I would:

```
SELECT country, COUNT(DATA) WHERE Date = 2013, COUNT(DATA) WHERE Date=2012 
FROM table 
GROUP BY Country
```

Which I know is not correct, but I'm wondering how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a CASE expression inside of your aggregate function to convert the rows of data into columns:

```
SELECT country, 
  sum(case when date = 2012 then 1 else 0 end) `2012`,
  sum(case when date = 2013 then 1 else 0 end) `2013`
FROM yourtable 
GROUP BY Country;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bd39c/7).

If you have an unknown number of years, or you want to implement a range of dates, then you can use a prepared statement to generate dynamic SQL:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'sum(CASE WHEN date = ',
      date,
      ' THEN 1 else 0 END) AS `',
      date, '`'
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM yourtable;

SET @sql 
  = CONCAT('SELECT country, ', @sql, ' 
            from yourtable
            group by country');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bd39c/9)

Comment: Looks good, but how to do it if you're not knowing the dates (2012, 2013)? You could set the range with min() and max() but what about the dates between?

Comment: It's VERY elegant and i love it, but it gives me the same sum for both 2013 and 2012 :(

Comment: @Mr.Bombastic See my edit with a dynamic version in the event there are unknown dates.

Comment: @BillCox Are you sure you have different data for each year?  Based on the sample data that you provided the demo shows the result is different for each year -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bd39c/1

Comment: Actually i don't use a SUM, but a COUNT, could it be the root of the issue ? i've updated my example accordingly. Also allow me to thank you as i've never seen such a fast answer ! Absolutely amazing

Comment: @BillCox See my edit, you just need to change the `then` part to use `1` instead of `data`.

Comment: @bluefeet : YOU TOTALLY ROCK it works. Is there anyway to make case on COUNT ?

Comment: @BillCox You can use `count(case when date = 2013 then 1 end)` instead of `sum`